# Is this equation to prove that $aRb \iff a^2 - b^2 = 1$ is antisymmetric correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, relations

> Over $\mathbb{R}$, $aRb \iff a^2 - b^2 = 1$.

I tried determining if it was antisymmetric. I seem to have done it, but while doing the equation, I stumbled upon a scenario that always made me doubt my decisions:

Have

$$aRb \land bRa$$

$$a^2 - b^2 = 1 \land b^2 - a^2 = 1$$

$$-a^2 + b^2 = -1 \land b^2 - a^2 = 1$$

$$-2a^2 + 2b^2 = 0$$

$$\color{#C00}{2(-a^2 + b^2) = 0}$$

$$\color{#C00}{-a^2 + b^2 = 0}$$

$$b^2 = a^2$$

$$b = a$$

I passed the $2$ to divide to the other side. The other side has a $0$, so the $2$ is essentially killed off with no apparent consequence.

Is this equation correct?

Comment: Besides the fact that the second line is superfluous and confusing (erase it, please), the last deduction is wrong: $$a^2=b^2\iff a=\pm b$$

Comment: This means that you have shown that $aRb \land bRa$ implies $a=\pm b$. It only remains to check whether $aRa$ and $aR(-a)$. If this cannot happen, you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deduction you have does not work, as $a^2 = b^2$ does not imply $a = b$. It is actually much simpler. Assuming $aRb$ and $bRa$, you get (third line of equations) $-a^2 + b^2 = -1$ and $b^2 - a^2 = 1$. So $b^2 - a^2$ must be equal to $1$ and $-1$ at the same time, which is not possible.

Comment: So it isn't antisymmetric? Or rather, it is antisymmetric since there is no counterexample?

Comment: It is antisymmetric. Antisymmetry means that for any distinct $a,b$ we cannot have $aRb$ and $bRa$ at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You're right just before the last step since $a^2=b^2$ does not imply $a=b$.
But the relation is antisymmetric (Hint: Try with difference of squares factorization when $a\neq0\neq b$).